# How to get contract address from its creation transaction on Ethereum?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I am trying to get to the contract addresses created in a specific block. I can get all transactions that create a new contract because their `To` value is always `0x0`. This tx also contains the compiled code in the `Input` parameter, however, it doesn't include the contract address. It is returned to the user at the time of creation but that is not helpful to me as I am not the one to create it.

Having a contract creation transaction, how can I find the contract address, on Ethereum?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's stored in the transaction receipt, property `contractAddress`.

Note that there are two transaction-related objects. The transaction itself that's available once the tx was broadcasted (before it's included in a block) - and the transaction receipt that becomes available after the transaction was included in a block.

RPC docs: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_gettransactionreceipt